# Go - The difference between var and func to define a function

Tags: go

I'm coming from an Scala background, and in Scala, you could define functions both as a single value, or an actual function, for instance:

```scala
val inc1: Int => Int = _ + 1 // single FUNCTION value
def inc2(x: Int): Int = x + 1 // normal function definition
// in this case "inc1 eq inc1" is true, since this is a single instance
// but "inc2 eq inc2" is false
```

And these 2 have some differences (i.e., size allocation, first one is a single instance, while the other one returns an instance each time it is invoked, ...), so based on the use case, we could kind of reason which one to use. Now I'm new to golang, and wanted to know if the below 2 function definitions (correct me if I'm wrong with the phrase) differ in Golang, and if so, what are differences?

```golang
var inc1 = func(x int) int { return x + 1 }
func inc2(x int) int { return x + 1 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala borrows a lot from [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).  Go does not.

(If you've used multiple other programming languages, you should definitely read the [Go specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec).  It's not very long as Go is not a very large language, although the new generics definitely complicate things a bit.)

In Go, the `func` keyword introduces a function definition or function type, with the details being context-dependent.  The `var` keyword introduces a variable declaration.<sup>1</sup>  So:

```
func inc2(x int) int { return x + 1 }
```

defines a function, `inc2`, whose code is as shown.  But:

```
var inc1 = // ...
```

declares and then initializes a variable, `inc1`.  The *type* and initial *value* of the variable are determined by the commented-out section, so:

```
var inc1 = func(x int) int { return x + 1 }
```

defines a function (with no name) whose code is as shown.  That function is then *assigned to* the variable as its initial value, so that the *implied type of the variable* is `func (int) int` or function taking one argument of type `int` and returning one value of type `int`.

Having created a variable, you can now either call the function currently stored *in* that variable:

```
func callit(arg int) {
    result := inc1(arg)
    // ... do something with the result ...
}
```

Or you can assign a new value into the variable, e.g.:

```
func overwrite() {
    inc1 = func(a int) int { return a * 2 } // name `inc1` is now misleading
}
```

Because `inc2` is a function, you can't re-assign a new value to it: it's just a function, not a variable.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that a variable declaration with an initialization can use the "short declaration" form:

```
func f() {
    v := 3
    // ...
 }
```

where we leave out the type and just say "use the type of the expression to figure out the type of the declaration".  This declares and initializes the variable.  Short declarations can only appear in block scope, so these must be inside some function.  Other than omitting the `var` keyword they do nothing that you couldn't do by including the `var` keyword, or sometimes multiple `var` keywords:

```
    result, err := doit()
```

might require:

```
    var result someType
    var err error
    result, err = doit()
```

when written without using the short-declaration form.

Comment: Thanks about the answer, it helped a lot. So based on my assumptions about your answer, the main difference would be that  inc2 is immutable, right? while inc1 is not. and as far as I could test, size allocation wouldn't differ in case of reassignment to the variable.

Comment: Yes, `inc2` is a function and functions cannot be redefined or changed (because Go is a statically-typed, compile-time-binding language). That makes it immutable. Note that you can, however, use *scope rules* to define a *different* `inc2` (function or variable) with a more-local scope, which will then shadow (hide away) the module-level `inc2`.